# closing collapsible menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to close the content of the collapsible menu when it is clicked using jquery.
Below I have attached the fiddle for reference.

```
<div id="advent">
    <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="margin-left:40px"></i>
    Advent
    <div id="expand" style="display:none">Content</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#advent').click(function () {
        $("#arrow", this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle");
        $('#expand').show();
        if($this.hasClass()){
            $('#expand').slideUp();
        }
    });
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5trqxn6t/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use toggle or slideToggle

```
$('#advent').click(function () {
    $("#arrow", this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle");
    $('#expand').slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5trqxn6t/5/

Comment: `.slideToggle()` is a simple and easy function. Didn't know it existed.

Comment: @FrankerZ could you please help me with this fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/5trqxn6t/10/

Comment: @Sindhu ID's are unique on a page. You need to switch to using classes: https://jsfiddle.net/5trqxn6t/12/

Comment: Yes.. I tried but the all the expand class are opening. https://jsfiddle.net/5trqxn6t/13/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$this`, so that entire clause doesn't work. Try using jQuery's `.is(':hidden')` to see if it's hidden, and toggle it that way:

```js
$('#advent').click(function () {
  $("#arrow", this).toggleClass("fa-minus-circle");
    if ($('#expand').is(':hidden')) {
   $('#expand').show();
    } else {
     $('#expand').slideUp();
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="advent">
  <i id="arrow" class="fa fa-plus-circle" style="margin-left:40px"></i>
  Advent
  <div id="expand" style="display:none">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great.. Thanks for the simple solution.. I have been looking for this solution for hours..